# Search an item in a complex object type list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List named users of type User, I searched for a particular user with the userID and I'm getting the details of that user but I want that searched User to be stored in User type variable, so that I could pass that particular user to the method which takes User type as parameter. Can I do this? Please help. Thanks.

**My Code:**

```
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        public void SearchUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter user id");
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var details = users.Where(i => i.ID == userID);
            Console.WriteLine("User Details are:");
            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Location);
            }
            User user = (User)details; //Here it throws exception, can I get the searched user as User type, so that I could pass it in the WritePost method
        }

       public void WritePost(User user)
       {
            //Code Here
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `First`/`FirstOrDefault` or `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` to get a single user from your list.

```
var user  = users.Where(i => i.ID == userID).First();
```

Or shorter:

```
var user = users.First(i=> i.ID == userID);
```

Remember :

> First => It would return the first item or throw an exception if none
>   is found
>
> FirstOrDefault => Returns first item or null if none is found

```
var user = users.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.ID == userID);
if(user == null)
     Console.WriteLine("User not found");
```

Since you are querying against an ID, it would be better if you use `Single/SingleOrDefault`, since it would throw an exception if more than one item is returned from query.

Comment: Or: users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == userID);

Comment: In his case, `Single` would be a better option

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 3):

`details` is of type `List<User>`, so you cannot cast to `User`.

I'd probably do something like:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

public void SearchUser()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter user id");
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var user = users.Where(i => i.ID == userID).SingleOrDefault();
    if(user == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User not found");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("User Details:");
    Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Location);
}
```